# Can't move uploaded file on Heroku

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, laravel-5, heroku

I have an ajax call that will upload a file to a Laravel app deployed at Heroku. This works flawless on my local environment.

On Heroku it will upload the file (I tried returning $logoImage in the ajax response and there is a tmp/whatever123 there) but when it's supposed to do the move, nothing happens. No file is put in the /public/img/local_logos folder. Also tried with only 'img/local_logos/' as path, which also works locally.

Could it be a https problem. I'm using https on Heroku. But then it should explode already when trying to upload the file. Sending normal forms with similar code works with no problems also in production.

Here's the function called by the ajax call.

```
 public function postLocalLogo(Request $request)
 {
    if ($request->hasFile('logoImage')) {
        $logoImage = $request->file('logoImage');
        $path = base_path() . '/public/img/local_logos/';

        $extension = $logoImage->getClientOriginalExtension();
        $fileName = md5($logoImage->getClientOriginalName() . microtime()) . '.' . strtolower($extension);
        $logoImage->move($path, $fileName); // This seems to not happen on Heroku

        $storageLogo = new StorageLogo();
        $storageLogo->filename = $fileName;
        $storageLogo->save();

        echo json_encode($fileName);
    }

}
```

and here's the ajax function:

```
 function uploadLogo() {
    deleteLogoFromServer();
    var logoFile = $('#logoImage')[0].files[0];

    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('logoImage', logoFile);

    $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });

    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/postajax',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        method: 'POST',
        success: function (data) {
                localStorage.setItem('logoFileName', data);
                $("#js-dataLocalLogo").val(localStorage.getItem('logoFileName'));
        },
        error: function (error) {
            alert(error);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please don't store files on Heroku's file system. If you ever restart, you will lose all the files.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I see your point. In this case they need to be stored in the public folder. We're planning an overhaul at a later date.

Comment: It will literally be lost daily, at the minimum. Sometimes it restarts even multiple times per day. The overhaul shouldn't be that bad. Get AWS. Buy S3. Change default file system to S3.

Comment: See the "BUT..." section of the duplicate answer.

Comment: See also https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm looking into this.

Comment: Than you so much @Ohgodwhy for pointing this out. I had to make a rehaul of big parts of the system. We're now using S3 and it's working really well.